# datanode took long time to become live after restart namenode or reboot

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari, datanode

As title, it always took about 20 mins or more for datanode to become live in hdfs summary. I couldn't find any clue about it. Is there any way to speed up the process ? Thanks.

Comment: Its all depends on your DataNode size. Basically NameNode need to get every block information from DataNode to mark its healthy

Comment: Thanks. So the less block the faster restart duration.